# Firestore architecture to develop explore feed that hides viewed posts

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am developing social app similar to twitter where users can browse posts.
What is the best way to organise documents in Firestone to implement EXPLORE feed that hides viewed posts?

My initial idea was:

Collections:

- Posts: to store all posts
- Users: to store all users

  - exploreFeed: to store personal explore feed

If users viewed some post we remove it from his personal exploreFeed (to hide viewed posts).

What worries me:
If new post published I have to add it in the each exploreFeed for each user. Sounds like a heavy operation (because I have 10k+ users in the system, but DAU is pretty low and in that case I have to make 10k+ duplicates for each new post in the system)

Is there any better solutions with lower number of writes to implement explore feed that hides viewed posts?

Comment: *"Sounds like a heavy operation"* Why do you say that? *"Is there any better solutions to implement explore feed"* Better in terms of what?

Comment: What do I mean – I have two feeds: explore and following. In terms of following this is the best solution, I just put a post to the user's feed (limited number of users). But in terms of explore, when new post publishes I have to put this post in EVERY user's feed, even for users that don't use the app for a long time and I have to do it for every new posts. I am looking for solution that will make less number of writes when new post publishes.

Comment: Have you tried to create a feed collection and load data for each user from there?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, the only problem in that case is that I can't hide viewed posts on the client side (or don't know how to do it)

Comment: Have you thought to add a flag to the viewed posts?

Comment: Right now I am trying to avoid generating personal explore feed if possible (to minimise number of writes with new published post). In case "viewed" field in the global feed I can't properly query it on the client side.